# Common formatter for all my child class with same name

Tags: javascript, class

I have a service that calls different providers of weather. I use a class to keep some data in common.

```
class Weather {
 providerName = ''
 constructor(providerName) {
  this.providerName = providerName
} 

class OpenWeather extends Weather {
   getTodayTemperature: () => this.get('http://openweather.com/weatherToday.......')
}


class TomorrowWeather extends Weather {
   getTodayTemperature: () => this.get('http://tommorow.io/weather.......')
}
```

The different APIs return data with different structures (normal) but all I want is to have way to format all getTodayTemperature function in all my child classes with the same structure.

```
Expected Result
{
 morning: 26,
 evening: 32
}
```

So for each return api i want to call a function

```
formatTemperature(morningNumber, eveningNumber)
```

Do you have a solution or another way to organize the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why can't you parse the return data in each of those functions and return standardized data?

Comment: Cause i have 30 different services and i don't want to duplicate the code

Comment: Ok, but then you should probably offer some examples of the return data. It's hard to offer solutions when we're guessing at what that might be.

Comment: I want to always validate the output of my functions, sometimes it's return { data : { morning, evening...} and some time { morningWeather: { data: { value: 12 } but i just thinks writing my question that the only one solution is to parse in each function

Comment: I want to have a function that validate my ouptut for all service (for example) function formatTodayTemperature(morningTemperature, afternoonTemperature)